# How to access text field value on same page without using $_post?

Tags: php, html

I have one text field with search button.

I want to access that text field's value on button click.

I can't use `$_post` because i have also one submit button inside.

So how to get that textfield's value  on search button click.

my below's entire form is based on that unique value which was entered in that textdield

```
    </head> 
    <script>
    var getData = function()
    {
        var value = $("#inputData").val();
        alert(value);
    }
    </script>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="pag3.php">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

//Other code for form which textfield should fill from data which match with
enterd value.

At end i have put submit button which will send data on next page form perform insertion

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to 'get' the value of the text field before / or without having to submit the form from the same page. If that's the case, you could use javascript `document.getElementById('yourtextfieldname').value`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery as follow

Html

```
<input type="button" name="" id="inputData">
<button onclick="return getData()" >Get Data</button>
```

script

```
var getData = function()
{
    var value = $("#inputData").val();
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: it is not call it move on to the page which i have specified in action="pag2.php" i am updating my question please try to give some solution